# Callback/Promises implementation for a boolean check

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Currently I have the following callback system:

```
var saveTask = function(err, result) {
    if (err) return callback(err, result);

    var newid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    var task = new Task({
        _id: newid,
        taskname: req.body.name,
        teamid: req.body.team,
        content: req.body.content,
        creator: req.user.userId
    });

    task.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            log.info("New task created with id: %s", task._id);
            return callback(null, task);
        } else {
            if(err.name === 'ValidationError') {
                return callback('400', 'Validation error');
            } else {
                return callback('500', 'Server error');
            }
            log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
        }
    });
};

if (req.body.team) {
    valTeam.isMember(req.body.team, req.user._id, function (err, done) {
        if (err) {
            saveTask('403', 'Not the owner or member of this team');
        } else {
            saveTask(null, true);
        }
    });
} else {
    saveTask(null, true);
}
```

**valTeam.isMember**

```
exports.isMember = function(teamid, userid, callback) {
    Team.find({'_id':teamid, $or:[{'creator': userid }, {'userlist': { $in : [userid]}}]}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return err;
            console.log(result);
            if (!result.length)
                return callback('404', false);
            else
                return callback(null, true);
    });
}
```

In short, if `team` is sent by `POST`, I'm checking if the user is member of that ID in `valTeam.isMember`. Am I using the correct syntax and best method to call back my `saveTask` function to save the task if the user is part of the team?

This code currently works, but I feel like there should be an easier way to do it? How could I use a promise to achieve the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Node.JS v6.x, or lower but with babel (this is ES6 syntax):

```
function saveTask(req) {
  // Always return a promise.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Build a task.
    const _id = mongoos.Types.ObjectId();
    const task = new Task({
      _id, // Not a mistake. it's valid ES6 code.
      taskname: req.body.name,
      teamid: req.body.team,
      content: req.body.content,
      createror: req.user.userId
    });

    // Save it.
    task.save((err) => {
      if (!err) {
        log.info('New task created with id: %s', _id);
        // Resolve promise with task.
        // If you don't actually need task, you could 
        // resolve(req); // to pass req along.
        resolve(task);
      } else {
        log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', err.code, err.message);
        // Reject promise with err.
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Utility function to run a specific code sequence.
const postTask = (req) => valTeam.isMember(req).then(saveTask);
// If `valTeam` is not a module library, then this might be better:
// const postTask = (req, valTeam) => valTeam.isMember(req).then(saveTask);
// and call with `postTask(req, valTeam)`
```

And here's the `isMember()` function

```
/**
 * Utility function to replace:
 *
 * if (req.body.team) { ... }
 *
 * with a promise.
 */
const hasTeamId = (req) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (req.body.team) {
    // Has team id. Pass `req`
    resolve(req);
  } else {
    reject(new Error('No team id provided'));
  }
});

// Function isMember() always returns a promise
module.exports.isMember = function (req) {
  const teamid = req.body.team;
  const userid = req.user._id;

  // Internal utility function to check if a given team it exists.
  const checkTeamExists = (req) => {
    // Execute query
    Team.findOne({'_id': teamid, $or:[{'creator': userid }, {'userlist': { $in : [userid]}}]}, function(err, result) {
      // On callback, solve the promise.
      if (!err && result) {
        // No error, and at least 1 document in results.
        // Resolve promise.
        resolve(req);
      } else {
        // 1) Either error, or
        // 2) No error, but empty results => Create a new error.
        // Reject promise.
        reject(err || new Error('404 - Not found'));
      }
    });
  };

  return hasTeamId(req).then(checkTeamExists);
};
```

Also, if you have Mongoose 4.x+ which supports Promises, better use this:

```
// ALTERNATIVE FOR MONGOOSE v4.x+
// Function isMember() always returns a promise
module.exports.isMember = function (req) {
  const teamid = req.body.team;
  const userid = req.user._id;

  // Internal utility function to check if a given team it exists.
  const checkTeamExists = (req) => {
    // Execute query ( In mongoose 4.x+, queries return Promises )
    return Team.findOne({'_id': teamid, $or:[{'creator': userid }, {'userlist': { $in : [userid]}}]})
      .then((result) => {
        // On callback, solve the promise.
        if (result) {
          //at least 1 document in results.
          return req;
        } else {
          // not found.
          throw new Error('404 - Not found');
        }
      });
  };

  return hasTeamId(req).then(checkTeamExists);
}
```

Finally, use the above like so:

```
postTask(req)
  .then((task) => {
    // Successfully saved task.
    // Handle task, if needed, otherwise just remove the `then()` branch.
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Some error occured, either in `isMember` or in `saveTask`
    // Handle error, if needed, otherwise just remove the `catch()` branch.
  });
```

Comment: Worked absolute wonders mate, thanks for your time and all the comments you wrote along the way. 

Just had one question, the `teamid` isn't a requirement, so I just need to bypass `checkTeamExists` and save the task without it. How would I be able to do so?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you want to bypass checking the database for `teamid` but keep the variable check inside `req`, just remove `.then(checkTeamExists)`. If you want to bypass `teamid` checks altogether (the `isMember()` function), just use `saveTask` instead of `postTask`. Promises give you this advantage of chaining various tasks, as needed.